# cat: read error: Operation not supported for /sys/class/net/eth0/phys_*

Tags: linux, sysfs

I customized the system using Kernel 6.4.0 and Busybox, but I don't know why the three files starting with `phys_` cannot be accessed, and other files in the same folder can.

```
# pwd
/sys/class/net/eth0
# ls
addr_assign_type      carrier_up_count      gro_flush_timeout     napi_defer_hard_irqs  proto_down            tx_queue_len
addr_len              dev_id                ifalias               netdev_group          queues                type
address               dev_port              ifindex               operstate             speed                 uevent
broadcast             device                iflink                phys_port_id          statistics
carrier               dormant               link_mode             phys_port_name        subsystem
carrier_changes       duplex                mtu                   phys_switch_id        testing
carrier_down_count    flags                 name_assign_type      power                 threaded
#
#
#
# cat dev_
dev_id    dev_port
# cat dev_port
0
# cat phys_port_id
cat: read error: Operation not supported
#
# ls -lt dev_port
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct 27 14:50 dev_port
# ls -lt phys_port_id
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct 27 15:36 phys_port_id
```

Comment: Please start tagging your questions with the appropriate tags.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have already seen the message you sent before, but because my shared value is not enough, I cannot add a finer tag on my end yet. I can only add a larger category tag.

Comment: @Kusalananda Also, it may be because I am unfamiliar with this area and did not attach a precise label, which caused confusion for everyone. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of that `phys_port_id` file is generated upon request (when a process reads it) by the [`phys_port_id_show()` function](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/core/net-sysfs.c?h=v6.4#n497) in the Linux kernel.

You can see that it returns `EOPNOTSUPP` if the driver for the network interface doesn't implement a `ndo_get_phys_port_id` operation. If you look for `ndo_get_phys_port_id` in the `drivers/net/ethernet` directory, you'll find that not many Ethernet drivers (Broadcom bnx2x, Intel i40e and a handful of others) implement it (probably because not many Ethernet hardware devices provide that information which as [detailed by @ChrisDavies](/a/760606) is only relevant for NICs with more than one port).

You can tell what driver drives your `eth0` ethernet device with:

```
readlink /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver
```

Or `ls -l /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver` if the `readlink` applet is not enabled in your build of busybox.

Answer (score 2):

None of the files under `/sys` are real - they are all representations of values maintained within the kernel.

A list of them under `/sys/class/net` is available at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net

The relevant section for `phys_port_id` and `phys_port_name` is this:

> ```
> What:     /sys/class/net/<iface>/phys_port_id
> Date:     July 2013
> KernelVersion:    3.12
> Contact:  netdev@vger.kernel.org
> Description:
>       Indicates the interface unique physical port identifier within
>       the NIC, as a string.
>
> What:     /sys/class/net/<iface>/phys_port_name
> Date:     March 2015
> KernelVersion:    4.0
> Contact:  netdev@vger.kernel.org
> Description:
>       Indicates the interface physical port name within the NIC,
>       as a string.
> ```

As described, these two values provide an identification for the physical port on a card with multiple ports (search for "4 port NIC", for example).

Comment: After reading this answer I still didn't know *why* the error. Neither the descriptions suggest that a card with a single port does not need to give support for these files, nor your answer clearly states "for a NIC with a single port these are not supported". *In general* there are situations where "1 entity" is a totally normal case of "N entities" (i.e. where N just *happens* to be 1) and all properties are present. I tend to expect such elegance, thus I did not see logic in your answer. Only after reading [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/760620/108618) I got it.